# How does ActionView::Template :render decide where to load from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, template-engine, actionview

Here's the problem, let's say I have a few resources that I want index all on the same page separated by tabs, in this case it's different types of content: videos, pdfs, etc. I also have a partial that gets included into several different views, in this case a search functionality. The partial does something like this to let you customize various parts of it:

**in _search.html.slim:**

```
.toolbar
  .left
    = render 'left_toolbar', f: f
```

The project tree looks something like:

```
app  
--views  
----media  
------index.html.slim  
------videos_list.html.slim  
------pdfs_list.html.slim  
------videos  
--------_left_toolbar.html.slim  
------pdfs  
--------_left_toolbar.html.slim
```

And I have a controller that manages requests coming in from the page with the various content-resources:

**in media_library_controller.rb:**

```
def index
end

def videos
  <sets everything needed to render a videos list, @videos etc.>
  render :index
end

def pdfs
  <sets everything needed to render a pdf list, @pdfs etc.>
  render :index
end
```

**And in the index.html.slim**

```
= render 'application/search'
ul.nav.nav-tabs
  li.active
    a href='#videosListTab' data-toggle='tab' Videos
  li
    a href='#pdfsListTab' data-toggle='tab' PDFs
ul.tab-content
  li.tab-pane.active#videosListTab
    .js-video-collection
      = render 'videos_list' if @videos
  li.tab-pane.active#pdfsListTab
    .js-pdf-collection
      = render 'pdfs_list' if @pdfs
```

**What I want is to be able to define in the controller which folder left_toolbar.html.slim is looked for when search.html.slim goes to look for it**

I have tried overriding `controller_path` which doesn't seem to work. `prepend_view_path` seems promising but it appends the controller name to the end of the view path so that I have something like `app/views/media_library/videos/media_library` when I set it. Any advice? I don't want to had a local to the search partial.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to be able to define in the controller which folder left_toolbar.html.slim is looked for when search.html.slim goes to look for it

---

[Perhaps you're getting ahead of yourself](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> `<%= render "shared/menu" %>`
>
> That code will pull in the partial from
>   app/views/shared/_menu.html.erb.

From what I understand of your question, you want to know how Rails can specify a specific path for your partial? There's no need - partials can be referenced from anywhere in your app.

So when you mention that `search.html` goes looking for it, you just have to prepend the folder for `left_toolbar` to the path:

```
render 'your_path/left_toolbar', f: f
```

---

Again, with your media tabs... they're all partials - just use the folder name in the partial path:

```
= render 'app/views/media_library/pdfs_list' if @pdfs
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear, but the search partial relies on overloading the template path. The 'shared' dir where search.html.slim lives there's a file called _left_toolbar.html.slim but it gets overridden by each resource by putting another file called _left_toolbar.html.slim in each folder corresponding to a controller. Rails the looks in the controller's folder first before looking in 'shared' for _left_toolbar.html.slim. This worlds fine for one resource-> one folder but as you can see now that I have multiple it gets hung up.